# why simple haskell add function doesn't behave as intended?

Tags: haskell

I'm playing with the haskell repo around a little. 
why f2 behaves that way ? (I was expecting f2 takes only 1 argument), also what does `t` mean in the type?

BTW, why I have to prefix repo with **let** in order to define function?

```
λ> :t add  -- f1
add :: Num a => a -> a
λ> let add n = (+) 1  -- f2 what does this mean?
λ> add 1 1
2
λ> :t add
add :: Num a => t -> a -> a
λ> add 1 3
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add n = (+) 1
```

You never use `n` on the right hand side. Keep in mind that `(+) 1` is short for `\x -> (+) 1`, and you'll see that

```
add n = (+) 1 = \x -> (+) 1 x
```

Or, equivalently

```
add n x = (+) 1 x
```

Therefore, `n` can be any type (here called `t`), since it is not used at all.

You meant

```
add n = (+) 1 n
```

> BTW, why I have to prefix repo with let in order to define function?

Because you're using GHCi, which doesn't act the same as using GHC on a source file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `n`, so it can be of any type you want. `t` is not some specific type, it means an argument of some type `t`.

A good indication that `t` is not used anywhere (and something is wrong) is the fact that only `a` has a `Num` constraint. So for `add` to work properly if it actually used `t` in the addition, it would have to somehow be able to add `a` to a variable of *any type*, including types that are not an instance of `Num`.